# java - assign value to int[] array in do-while loop

Tags: java, arrays, do-while

Coming from ruby/rails I have lots of difficulties adopting Java logic.

**Question** - how to assign values (read from stdin) to arrays of integers in do-while loop to use those arrays later in later methods?

Here is my code snippet:

```
void triAnglePerimeter() {
        //int[][] arrs;
        //int[] edge1, edge2, edge3 = new int[];
        do {
            System.out.print("X, Y for edge 1: ");
            int[] edge1 = {Ch3Ex.stdin.nextInt(),Ch3Ex.stdin.nextInt()};
            System.out.print("X, Y for edge 2: ");
            int[] edge2 = {Ch3Ex.stdin.nextInt(),Ch3Ex.stdin.nextInt()};
            System.out.print("X, Y for edge 3: ");
            int[] edge3 = {Ch3Ex.stdin.nextInt(),Ch3Ex.stdin.nextInt()};
            int[][] arrs = {edge1,edge2,edge3};

            if (!(TriangleHelpers.inputValidityChecker(arrs)))
                System.out.println("Wrong input. Retype."); 

        } while(!(TriangleHelpers.inputValidityChecker(arrs)));

        Triangle triAngle = new Triangle();
        triAngle.computeSides(arrs);

        System.out.printf("Triangle perimeter == %.2f\n", triAngle.perimeter());
    }
```

==================

**Ch3Ex.stdin.nextInt();** - Scanner object that reads from System.in

==================

**Console errors:**

```
Tasks3.java:209: error: cannot find symbol
        } while(!(TriangleHelpers.inputValidityChecker(arrs)));
                                                       ^
  symbol:   variable arrs
  location: class Tasks3
Tasks3.java:212: error: cannot find symbol
        triAngle.computeSides(arrs);
                              ^
  symbol:   variable arrs
  location: class Tasks3
2 errors
```

**If I do:**

- without do-while, everything works perfectly;
- declare arrays above do-while and remove declarations in do-while only leaving:

  edge1 = {Ch3Ex.stdin.nextInt(),Ch3Ex.stdin.nextInt()};

then I get
`Tasks3.java:199: error: illegal start of expression
            edge1 = {Ch3Ex.stdin.nextInt(),Ch3Ex.stdin.nextInt()};`

- declaration and memory assign outside do-while:

  int[] side1 = new int[2];

and inside do-while assign values separately:

```
side[0] = Ch3Ex.stdin.nextInt();
```

everything also works perfectly.

========

**Where is my problem understanding the logic of arrays + loops**

Comment: Use `edge1 = new int[]{Ch3Ex.stdin.nextInt(),Ch3Ex.stdin.nextInt()};` instead of `edge1 = {Ch3Ex.stdin.nextInt(),Ch3Ex.stdin.nextInt()};`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

Declare

```
int[][] arrs;
int[] edge1, edge2, edge3;
```

outside do-while loop.

Inside do-while loop do the following:

```
edge1 = new int[]{Ch3Ex.stdin.nextInt(),Ch3Ex.stdin.nextInt()};
```

for every 1-dim array
and

```
arrs = new int[][]{edge1,edge2,edge3};
```

for 2-dim array.